# How to print only the last array for bubble_sort

Tags: c++

How do i get it to print only the last array for bubble_sort, it keeps printing all the array numbers for bubble_sort.

```
void bubble_sort(int iarr[], int num)
{

int i, j, k, temp;

for (i = 1; i < num; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < num - 1; j++)
    {
        if (iarr[j] > iarr[j + 1])
        {
            temp = iarr[j];

            iarr[j] = iarr[j + 1];

            iarr[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
    printf("\nAfter pass %d : ", i);

    for (k = 0; k < num; k++)

    {
        printf("\t%5d", iarr[k]);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

take your `print` `for loop` out of the `sort` `for loop`.

Answer (score 0):

Move your for-loop for printing outside of your for-loop for sorting. Just like

```
void bubble_sort(int iarr[], int num)
{

    int i, j, k, temp;

    for (i = 1; i < num; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < num - 1; j++)
        {
            if (iarr[j] > iarr[j + 1])
            {
                temp = iarr[j];

                iarr[j] = iarr[j + 1];

                iarr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nAfter pass %d : ", i);
    for (k = 0; k < num; k++)

    {
        printf("\t%5d", iarr[k]);
    }

}
```

And do proper code formatting to avoid such mistakes.